# WebView с переносом слов Windows

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

Создаю универсальное приложение - справочник. Столкнулся с некоторыми проблемами.
Статьи грузятся из html страничек.

```
        private void listView_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        var selected = e.ClickedItem as Listnewitems;
        string url = "ms-appx-web:///Html/" + selected.url +".html";
        htmlPage.Navigate(new Uri(url));
    }
```

XAML

```
        <Grid  Grid.Column="2" Background="White">       
            <WebView x:Name="htmlPage" 
                    Margin="10,10,10,30"/>
        </Grid>
```

Хотелось бы что бы при увеличении  текста (колесо мышки+ctrl)  был такой же эффект как на картинке
[image: Вот так хотелось бы]

а он выходит за рамки, что не удобно.

[image]

Comment: при увеличении колесом мышки хотелось бы что бы текст переносился, а он расширяется и что бы увидеть весь текст необходимо работать горизонтальным скролом.

Comment: Лучший способ что я нашел, это использовать javascript в HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Единственный способ, который я нашел, это использовать JS в подгружаемых html

```
<html>
........

<style>
   .colortext2 {
     color: blue; /* синий цвет выделения */
   }
      #footer {
    position: fixed; /* Фиксированное положение */
    left: 0; bottom: 0; /* Левый нижний угол */
    padding: 10px; /* Поля вокруг текста */
    background: #00574F; /* Цвет фона */
    color: #fff; /* Цвет текста */
    width: 100%; /* Ширина слоя */
   }
    #links {
        color: white
    }

    #content {
        margin: 10px 0px 50px 0px;
    }
</style>

<script>
var tgs = new Array('p');
var szs = new Array( 'xx-small','x-small','small','medium','large','x-large','xx-large' );
var startSz = 3;

function ts( trgt,inc ) {
 if (!document.getElementById) return
 var d = document,cEl = null,sz = startSz,i,j,cTags;

 sz += inc;
 if ( sz < 0 ) sz = 0;
 if ( sz > 6 ) sz = 6;
 startSz = sz;

 if ( !( cEl = d.getElementById( trgt ) ) ) cEl = d.getElementsByTagName( trgt )[ 0 ];

 cEl.style.fontSize = szs[ sz ];

 for ( i = 0 ; i < tgs.length ; i++ ) {
 cTags = cEl.getElementsByTagName( tgs[ i ] );
 for ( j = 0 ; j < cTags.length ; j++ ) cTags[ j ].style.fontSize = szs[ sz ];
 }
 var imgs = cEl.getElementsByTagName("img")
 for (ij = 0; ij < imgs.length ; ij++) {
     if (inc == 1) {
    imgs[ij].style.width = imgs[ij].clientWidth  * 1.2 + 'px';
     imgs[ij].style.height = imgs[ij].clientHeight * 1.2 + 'px';}    

     else {
         imgs[ij].style.width = imgs[ij].clientWidth  / 1.2 + 'px';
     imgs[ij].style.height = imgs[ij].clientHeight / 1.2 + 'px';}
     }

}
</script>

.......
</head>

<body>
    <div id="footer">
        <a id="links" href="javascript:ts('body',1)">+ Увеличить шрифт</a> |
        <a id="links" href="javascript:ts('body',-1)">- Уменьшить шрифт</a>
    </div>

<div id="content">
.................
</div>
</body>
</html>
```